# Unable to query local database Query was empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm in the process of refactoring my DAL and I will now start using `mysqli` and prepared statements. My first task is to use `mysqli` so I'm testing this now.

This is my DAL class. This is just part of the code I use:

```
class DAL {
  private $mysqli;
  (...)

  // Create new mysqli object
  private function conn() {
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->pwd, $this->dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno(); exit();
    }    
  } 

  public function getRowByValue($table,$column, $value)
  {   
    $this->conn(); 
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM sl_store LIMIT 5");
    $result->close();
}
```

When executing the mysqli query, I only get this result: `Unable to query local database Query was empty`.
I've tested the SQL code in Toad and it returns 5 rows.

So why am I getting this error / what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if no processing on your query is needed (no variable interpretation etc.) it could be possible, that query() needs a string delimited with " instead of '. Just a guess because of this example from php.net

```
if (!$mysqli->query("SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
```

Comment: Hi, I've tested the code locally, and it worked. A reason might be accessing $result AFTER closing it. What does echo $this->mysqli->error; say, after executing the query? The given result?

Comment: Fore some reason it'w working now. I'm not sure why, because I haven't really done any changes to the code. Since you were the only one trying to help. I'll give you the cred :)